# Django Toolbar Does not list queries from custom views

Tags: django

I've setup djangotoolbar 1.3.2 with django1.8.
For the admin pages, it does list all the queries that are occurring but for custom views, it is not displaying them with the exception of the session query.

What is causing it not display queries from custom views?

Here are my configurations:

settings.py

```
if DEBUG:
    INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    )

    INSTALLED_APPS += (
        'debug_toolbar',
    )

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
        'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
        'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
    ]

    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
        'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
    }
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    )
```

I also tried putting the DebugToolbarMiddleware at the top of the list. Still it is not displaying queries from my custom views.

Answer (score 0):

I added the ip address of the machine from which I used the browser to view the django page to the INTERNAL_IPS.
I also closed and reopen my browser because there was something weird going on with the browser.
Now it's working.
Anyway, the information above is enough to make it work. If it does not work for you, then you'll have to make sure that the ip address is correct.